# Parsing nested HTML unordered lists with Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, html-lists, jsoup

I am parsing an HTML file with nested unordered lists, here is an example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="category_x">xyz abc
        <ul>
            <li>foo 123 bar</li>
            <li>456 bar foo</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category_x">aaa bbb ccc
        <ul>
            <li>xxx yyy zzz</li>
            <li>123 abc 456</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am interested in the relationship `li > ul > li` (think at it as Jsoup objects of type `Element`: `grandParentNode` > `parentNode` > `eNode`), but using the method `grandParentNode.text()` I am getting also the text in the whole nested `<ul>` list (included `eNode.text()`).

```
    // getting the triplets
    Elements triplets = doc.select("li > ul > li");

    // print the triplet
    for (Element eNode : triplets)
    {
        Element parentNode = eNode.parent();
        Element grandParentNode = parentNode.parent();

        System.out.println("Current node: " + eNode.text());
        System.out.println("Grand parent: " + grandParentNode.text());
    }
```

The output is:

```
Current node: foo 123 bar
Grand parent: xyz abc foo 123 bar 456 bar foo
Current node: 456 bar foo
Grand parent: xyz abc foo 123 bar 456 bar foo
Current node: xxx yyy zzz
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc xxx yyy zzz 123 abc 456
Current node: 123 abc 456
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc xxx yyy zzz 123 abc 456
```

I would like it to be:

```
Current node: foo 123 bar
Grand parent: xyz abc
Current node: 456 bar foo
Grand parent: xyz abc
Current node: xxx yyy zzz
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc
Current node: 123 abc 456
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc
```

Having a look at the Jsoup documentation it seems I need to modify the HTML in order to get those strings included in something like a `value=""` attribute, but I can not modify the HTML... 
On top of this all those `<li class="category_x">` are repeated everywhere with the same value on every node which is not a "`li` leaf" of the tree, so they are not really helpful in filtering data.

I have already tried stuff like `doc.select("li:lt(1) > ul > li");` but it's not working, the problem is the structure of the HTML and how I am using the method `text()` from the `Element` class of Jsoup. The thing is that I have no idea of how to avoid `text()`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ownText()` method to select only the text owned directly by an Element, ignoring the text of any child Elements.

So change this line:

```
System.out.println("Grand parent: " + grandParentNode.text());
```

to

```
System.out.println("Grand parent: " + grandParentNode.ownText());
```

The output will now show:

```
Current node: foo 123 bar
Grand parent: xyz abc
Current node: 456 bar foo
Grand parent: xyz abc
Current node: xxx yyy zzz
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc
Current node: 123 abc 456
Grand parent: aaa bbb ccc
```